# Can't assign created_by as current_user. Database is saving as nil. Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a userstamps method to know which user created and edited a data. I have this table Illustrator that I am trying to assign created_by to the current_user id. But when it saves, created_by is nil and don't show any error. When I put raise right before illustrator.save, the @illustrator.created_by is exactly the current_user.id but when I check the value in db, is nil.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
          :custom_authenticatable
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :role
  cattr_accessor :current_user
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :email, format: { with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP }
  validates :password,
            length: { minimum: 6 },
            if: -> { new_record? || !password.nil? }
  enum gen: { masculino: 1, feminino: 2 }
   
   private

  #apenas usuário com role de admim pode logar.
  def valid_for_custom_authentication?(password)
    #self.role.name == 'admin'
    self.role_id === 2
  end

end
```

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  helper_method :current_user

  private
  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

end
```

```
class IllustratorsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

    def new
      @illustrator = Illustrator.new
    end
    
    def create
      @illustrator = Illustrator.new(illustrator_params)
      @illustrator.created_by = current_user.id
      if @illustrator.save
        redirect_to illustrator_path(@illustrator), notice: 'O autor foi criado com sucesso.'
      else
        render :new
      end
    end
  
    private
  
    def illustrator_params
      params.require(:illustrator).permit(:name, :display_name, :email, :phone, :status, :notes, :created_by)
    end

  end
```

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'payments/index'
  devise_for :users

  root to: 'pages#home'

  resources :books
  resources :authors
  resources :publishers
  resources :illustrators
  
  resources :plans do
    resources :accounts, only: %i[new create] do
    end
  end

  resources :payments, only: %i[index]

  resources :accounts, only: %i[index show edit update destroy] do
    resources :users, only: %i[new create] do
      resources :roles
    end
  end
  
  resources :users, only: %i[edit update index show destroy]

  #API routes
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      get 'default/:id', to: 'plans#change_plans'
      get 'plans', to: 'plans#index'
      get 'plans/id', to: 'plans#show'
      get 'accounts', to: 'accounts#return'
      post 'users', to: 'users#create'

      #resources :users
      post '/auth/login', to: 'authentication#login'
      get '/*a', to: 'application#not_found'

      post 'password/forgot', to: 'users#forgot_password'
    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using devise, you dont need this part:

```
  helper_method :current_user

  private
  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end
```

Where did you even find it? Remove it from your codebase!

With `devise` you don't need any getter or setter methods.

It can possibly be the reason it's not working for you.

If in `application_controller` you have the `before_action :authenticate_user!`, `current_user` method should work right out of the box!

As well you don't need to add the `before_action :authenticate_user!` again here

```
class IllustratorsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
```

, because you already made it **application-wide** in application_controller.

Your `create` method is good. Try removing the abundancies and it should all work.

Answer (score 0):

You have just setter method in your controller where you are setting current_user

```
  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end
```

You need to add getter method as well like following so that you can use it in your controller

```
def current_user
  @current_user
end
```

In ruby there is short cut for this `attr_accessor :current_user` Ref [this](https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/11/attr_accessor/)

Comment: Hello Salil :) well, it worked but now @illustrator.created_by is saving as nil.

Comment: You are using devise gem so no need to use `current_user` methods explicitly

Comment: I delete the method but still created_by is saving as nil :(

Comment: Try `before_action ->{ authenticate_user!(force: true) }`